# Storing a reference in another collection creates object but not string Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am uploading profile pictures for my users using collectionFS. I have two collections, one for userData and another for Images. I am trying to attach the image reference in the other collection. But I am getting the object rather than the _id string. Any pointers?

```
Biye = new Meteor.Collection ('biye');

Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.GridFS("images")]
});
```

```
// .....................upload.............

Template.upload.events({
  'change #exampleInput':function(event, template){  
    var file = $('#exampleInput').get(0).files[0]; 
    newFile = new FS.File(file);
    newFile.metadata = {'ownerId':Biye.findOne({ObjectID:this._id})};
    Images.insert(newFile,function(err,result){
      if(!err){
        console.log(result._id);
       }
     });
   }
})
```

```
newFile.metadata = {'ownerId':Biye.findOne({ObjectID:this._id})};
```

this line returns a whole object. I wanted a string.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to store the string using

```
newFile.metadata = {'ownerId':Biye.findOne({ObjectID:this._id})._id};
```

just added ._id at the end of

```
 newFile.metadata = {'ownerId':Biye.findOne({ObjectID:this._id})};
```

Comment: by the way, kyll could you please look at this problem ? I am stuck there for some time now             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677166/how-to-show-currect-profile-picture-meteorjs/32678196?noredirect=1#comment53300854_32678196